# UITableView reordered cells not retaining its state after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on UITableView with dynamic number of rows & sections. I have stored all  my data's (rows and section values) in an NSMutableDictionary like this.
    {
    Fruits = [Apple, Orange, PineApple],
    Cars = [Ferrari, Porsche, Audi]
    }

Here Fruits & cars are my section titles while its values are my corresponding rows. Fine. I'm following Raywanderlich's tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture) to reorder my UITableView cells within the section by long pressing the row. This works perfect. My problem is, after reordering my cells, when I scroll to the bottom or top of my table, the reordered cells goes back to its initial position. But, I want them to stay in its reordered position even after scrolling or reloading.

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @HotLicks: Thank you. Can you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: When you scroll down, cells that scroll off the top are removed and placed in a pool of reusable cells.  When you scroll back up, cells are extracted from that pool in random order when requested by `cellForRow...`.  If you rearranged the visible cells and not your data source array the cell order will be wrong.  If you do not appropriately "cleanse" the recycled cells they will contain the wrong stuff.

Comment: @HotLicks. What is that "appropriate" cleanse?

Comment: As you reorder the cells, you have to reorder the arrays of the underlying model arrays. If you do that, then as you scroll around and it has to inquire from the `UITableViewDataSource`, it will reflect the reordered model.